# Showing a single value from api call TextBlock (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have been stuck on this for a few hours now. I am using the IGDB api for the application I'm building. So, I'm trying to get the ListBox I have to show the Game Title, cover and Developer. I've managed to get all of them to show up in the list with no issues but the main issue comes in when I just want to show a single developer within the list, the list is showing all companies involved plus the developer because the API returns an array of Involved Companies and within those Involved Companies the developer body returns a Boolean value to say which one is the developer. I can see it in my head, if developer is true then show the developer and remove the other involved companies. Here is an image of what is showing up when I run my query:

[Query Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9qQm.jpg)

I have outlined it in red. From that list all I would need is Bungie since they're the developers. So in my view I have a ListBox and a ListView nested within it:

**BrowseGamesView**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Games}"
             Width="390"
             Height="500"
             Grid.Row="4">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            Margin="0 0 10 0">
                        <Image Source="{Binding cover.image_id, Converter={StaticResource stringToImage}}"
                               Stretch="Fill"
                               Height="70"
                               Width="60"/>
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="0"/>
                    <ListView Grid.Column="1"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding involved_companies}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding company.name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Within my ViewModel I have a method for making the query and also holds the ObservableCollection (Games).

**BrowseGamesViewModel**

```
public ObservableCollection<Game> Games { get; set; }

public async void MakeQuery()
        {
            var games = await IGDBHelper.GetGames(Query);

            Games.Clear();
            foreach(var game in games)
            {
                Games.Add(game);
            }
        }
```

In my Helper class I get the games

**IGDBHelper**

```
public static async Task<List<Game>> GetGames(string query)
        {
            List<Game> games = new List<Game>();

            string myJson = "search \"{0}\"; fields name, cover.url, cover.image_id, involved_companies.developer, involved_companies.company.name; limit 500;";

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-key", "key hidden");

                var response = await client.PostAsync(BASE_URL_GAMES, new StringContent(string.Format(myJson, query), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                games = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Game>>(responseString);
            }

            return games;
        }
```

And all of models are concrete classes for the Json

```
public class Game
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public Cover cover { get; set; }
        public List<InvolvedCompany> involved_companies { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }


public class InvolvedCompany
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public Company company { get; set; }
        public bool developer { get; set; }
    }

public class Company
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

public class Cover
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string image_id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

So, to reiterate, I need to somehow just show the developers name by removing the rest of the involved companies from the list. I have tried several things from converters to trying it in the converter class and each time I get exceptions for null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a new readonly property to the `Game` class:

```
public List<InvolvedCompany> DeveloperCompanies 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return involved_companies.Where(c => c.developer == true).ToList();  
    } 
}
```

And then you can bind this new property to your ListView:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.Row="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DeveloperCompanies}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding company.name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This way you would be showing only the developer companies but you would keep the information about all the involved companies as well, if you need to use them for another purpose.

I also suggest you to use PascalCase for the public members of a class. So, for example `involved_companies` would become `InvolvedCompanies`.

Comment: Thanks for this. It works perfectly and makes a lot more sense to me now. For some reason when I would use PascalCase I could not get the Json to Deserialize properly. Any ideas on why that would happen? Example if I use a property from Cover.cs such as image_id and I change it to ImageId it no longer works even after changing all of its references in code. Also the code will throw out a null exception when scrolling through the results. Would it be better to just wrap it in a try/catch?

Comment: That's because because the web service you are getting this information from is serializing to Json using the property name as snake_case (image_id, involved_companies etc). If you can't change this, then use snake_case as well as you did. It is fine. They must match for you to be able to deserialize to a concrete class.

Comment: Okay. What about the ArgumentNullException? I can't seem to figure out how to solve that outside of a try/catch statement.

Comment: Nevermind I figured out the ArgumentNullException. I just added add null check to the involved companies and return a new list if it is. Thanks for the help again :)

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest to name your properties in PascalCase.
Now for your problem, I suggest to filter the companies by developer property and assign a new list of involving companies to the game before adding it to the list.

```
foreach(var game in games)
  {
     game.involved_companies = game.involved_companies.Where(e => e.developer == true).Tolist();
     Games.Add(game);
  }
```

Not tested but I believe this should work.

Comment: This works, it will throw a null exception but I can work around that.